# using requests to check dead URLs

Tags: python, url

I am using the requests library to check a number of URLs. The aim is to see if they still alive or not. The code is very simple

```
import requests

def checkurlalive(url):
    r = requests.head(url,timeout=10)
    if r.ok:
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

However, it does not work for the following URL:

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx5/6294/4804034/04804053.pdftp=&arnumber=4804053&isnumber=4804034

This URL works on my computer as it shows a PDF file, however, the method above gives me a 
requests.exceptions.Timeout error.

On the other hand, the following URL:

```
http://www.wartsila.com/ss/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheader=JPG&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1278606917069&ssbinary=trueaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

should NOT be a valid URL but the method above gives me a positive result.

How could that be?

Comment: The first URL returns True for me. The second does too, as it should. Why do you say it is not valid?

Comment: I tried your code using both URLs you provided, and got `True` for both. Why? Because both have a web server listening on the other end, accepting connections. I think you're conflating "alive" with "valid and useful". If the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) can be resolved to an IP address at which something is listening on port 80, chances are your code is going to say the URL is "alive".

Comment: @JosephDunn, It's not just the FQDN, it's the whole address. If you try `checkurlalive("http://www.wartsila.com/ss/fsfsdaf")` it gives you `False`. Still, my earlier comment stands. By the way, I'm using requests 0.12 on Python 2.7.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, @PauloAlmeida. I see now that it only returns `True` for reponse codes in `requests.codes.ok`.

Comment: Btw @PauloAlmeida, my original comment wasn't directed at you, but at OP. :)

Comment: @JosephDunn Anyway, you do have a point, because the response can be valid even if the page doesn't exist, if the server takes care of it. ieee.org redirects pages that don't exist and you get the `ok`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I was running the code above on a server and it does give me a time out error, but when I run the code on a desktop, it runs OK. I was using Python 2.6.6 and Requests 1.2.3. I believe it is not an issue of Python but an issue of the server itself. Maybe a firewall issue.